# Que version de gvNIX y roo elegir

Tags: spring-mvc, gvnix, spring-roo

Queria saber que versión de gvNIX conviene utilizar.

Veo que la última que se lanzó fue la 1.5.1.rc4 pero una anterior a esta es la que tiene soporte para roo 2.0.xx

Por otro lado tampoco consigo la version de roo 2.0.0.M1, en la pagina del peoyecto solo deja descargar la version M3. Alguien podria darme el link?? Gracias!!

Por último queria saber si gvNIX sigue con soporte porque veo que la última versión fue lanzada hace mas de un año.

Saludos!

Comment: Trata en [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/releases/tag/2.0.0.M1). Un repositorio git contiene las versiónes anteriores en un clone, así puedes volver a la versión que necesitas. Generalmente es recomendable mientras combinas componentes de trabajar con las versiones mas recientes conocidos de funcionar juntos sin incompatibilidades. Personalmente lo encuentro valido de preguntar hasta que versiones hay experiencias concretas sobre la interacción de componentes. Trata preguntar en esta forma para no atraer respuestas de baja calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Descargar la versión 2.0.0.M1 de Roo:

http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org.s3.amazonaws.com/milestone/ROO/spring-roo-2.0.0.M1.zip

En cuanto a qué versión utilizar depende de tus necesidades:

- gvNIX incluye soporte Geo en tus aplicaciones pero genera apps basadas en Spring 3
- Spring Roo 2.0.x no incluye soporte Geo pero genera apps con tecnología mucho más actual: Spring 4, Spring Boot, etc.

Por último sobre el soporte, entiendo que como cualquier proyecto Open Source, analiza la activdad de su comunidad y saca tus propias conclusiones.

Answer (score 0):

Ya se ha publicado la nueva versión 2.0.0.RC1 de Spring Roo. Puedes encontrarla aquí:

http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org.s3.amazonaws.com/milestone/ROO/spring-roo-2.0.0.RC1.zip

Un saludo,

Comment: Hola @jcgarcia, por favor, échale un vistazo a [answer]. Bienvenido a SO en español.